# How to get data from the child date

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();

```
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM YYYY  'at' HH:mm:ss a");
    String  saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForDate.getTime());

    Calendar today = calForDate;
    final DatabaseReference orderlistref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Order");


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Order> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Order>()
                    .setQuery(orderlistref.child(CurrentUser).child("Items").child(saveCurrentDate), Order.class).build();
```

Kindly review my code and give feedback how to get data from the child date.

Comment: Please add some context to your code/question

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. Also beware of the case of pattern format letters. Check the documentation for the difference between uppercase `YYYY` and lowercase `yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Order").child(CurrentUser).child("Items").child(saveCurrentDate).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    //Your Code
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I hope that can help you.

Thank You.

Comment: please check update i write by mistake **items** but in your database name is **Items** So,write **Items** in child.